# How can I compute the posterior probability ( P(y | x) ) with Python and Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability, probability-density

For a dataset of classes I have to compute the function `posterior()`, where

- x - the dataset
- array of means for each class
- array of standard deviations for each class
- the prior probability for each class ( p(y)
- i - an index to access each of the classes

I want to make use of the Bayes rule, which comes to `P(y | x) = (p(x | y) * p(y)) / sum( p(x | y) * p(y) )`, but since I don't have access to `p(x | y)`, I don't know how to tackle the problem

Comment: I'm asking how to overcome the problem of not being able to access p(x | y), otherwise I know what I have to do

Comment: because it seems like a circular problem - to calculate p(y | x) I have to use p(x | y), but since I don't know how to compute the first conditional how should I compute the second one? There must be something I'm missing

Comment: Since you are given a dataset `x`, I would assume that `p(x | y)` should be derived from the dataset `x`, e.g., by computing the emperical distribution. How does `x` look like? Is `x` a discrete variable?